# What is the difference between <> and == in python?

Tags: python-2.7

```
In [142]: (MON,TUE,WED,THR,FRI,SAT,SUN)<>range(7)
Out[142]: True

In [143]: (MON,TUE,WED,THR,FRI,SAT,SUN)==range(7)
Out[143]: False
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/comparisons.html

Comment: The former operator "<>" means "not equal to" while the latter "==" means "equal to". Just take a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/comparison_operators_example.htm to learn more about operators in python.

Comment: Why on earth did you revert an edit making your post readable? Also, why haven't you just tried your code, or read the manual (e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator "<>" means 'not equal to', and the operator "==" means 'equal to'. The former evaluates to true if two things being compared are not equal, and the latter evaluates to true if two things being compared are equal.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/comparison_operators_example.htm